# How to start interval readily after the last one has been cleared?

Tags: javascript

I tried to copy the preview animation Of StackOverflow which changes the jobs infinitely.
My problem is when I clear Interval and then I start interval again I get some sort of delay, there's way to start the interval immediately after I cleared the previous ???

```js
const jobs = ["developer", "data scientist", "system admin"," mobile developer","game developer"]
const jobsBox = document.querySelector('.jobs')

function* genPositon(){
    let size = jobs.length;
    let counter = 0;
    for(let i = 0 ; i <= size; i++){
        yield counter++;    
    }
}
function RepeatJobs(){
    const gen = genPositon();
    const start = setInterval(() => {
        var next = gen.next();             
        if(next.done){ 
            clearInterval(start)                   
            RepeatJobs()
        } else {
            jobsBox.textContent = jobs[next.value];       
        }
    }, 3000)
}

RepeatJobs()
```

```html
    <div class="animation1">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1 class="sentence">Every <span class="jobs">  </span> has a</h1> 
            <h1 class="sentence">tab open to Stack Overflow</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Instead of restarting, you can simply make your generator yield infinitely using the [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) operator `while (true) {yield (counter++)%size;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be significantly easier using async rather than sync iterators:

```js
// Note the async
async function* generateJobs(){
    while(true) { // repeat the iteration until the generator is closed
      for (const job of jobs) { // yield the job rather than the position
        yield job;
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000)); // can wait in generator
      }
    } 
}
```